# Any way to check if action was successful in after_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

As the title states, I'm looking for a method that allows me to check if action (create, update, destroy) was successfull in an `after_filter`. The reason is that I want to possibly set a flash message and eventually redirect `create` and `update` actions to `edit` instead of show.

Currently I'm doing this as an action inside `controller` block, but would be easier with a before filter because I can plug-in multiple things after the action is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a simple way.
I solved with a module that can be added to controller and does the following:

```
  module ActionStatus

    [:create, :update, :destroy].each do |parsed_action|
      define_method(parsed_action) do |&block|
        super() do |success, failure|
          @action_successful = failure.instance_of?(
            InheritedResources::BlankSlate
          ) || failure.class.nil?
          block.call(success, failure) unless block.nil?
        end
      end
    end

    def action_successful?
      @action_successful = false if @action_successful.nil?
      @action_successful
    end

    def action_failure?
      !action_successful?
    end

  end
```

I know the check on `failure` class is horrible, but it was the only dirty-and-fast-hack to make it works.
Notice that the module must be included before any other module that uses it.

Answer (score 4):

Because we already have a declaration in controllers that signifies success/failure, we ought to avoid duplicating the effort.

You can use `response.status` code to determine whether your action succeeded. And this assumes you follow the convention which 99% of time we do.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_action :maybe_flash
  private
  def succeeded?
    response.status < 400 && response.status >= 200
  end

  def maybe_flash
    # do something here
  end
end
```

imagine you have a `phones_controller.rb`

def update
    @phone = Phone.find(params[:id])

```
respond_to do |format|
  # if @phone.update_attributes(params[:phone])
  if @phone.update_attributes phone_params
    format.html { redirect_to @phone, notice: 'Phone was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @phone.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

that `status` tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: It appears you can also use `response.successful?`. [Source](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/36679765cd0026d6dbd16d34a179eb3b3cc2565d/lib/rack/response.rb#L125)